# нужно сделать значение a либо b строго больше, чем некоторое данное число 

Tags: python, python-3.x

нужно сделать значение a либо b строго больше, чем некоторое данное число . Нужно вычислить через сколько попыток А или Б превысит число N. если выполнить «a += b», когда a = 2, b = 3, значение a станет равно 5 (значение b при этом не изменится).

```
t = int(input())
i = 0
while i < t:
    data = list(map(int,input().split()))
    a = data[0]
    b = data[1]
    n = data[2]
    i += 1
    count = 0
    while a < n and b < n:
        if count % 2 == 1:
            a += b
            count += 1
        if count % 2 == 0:
            b += a
            count += 1

    print(count)
```

Comment: Вопрос-то какой? Чем приложенный код не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в том, как исправить приведённый код - сделать

```
while a <= n and b <= n:
    a += b
    b += a
    count += 1
```

поскольку спрашивается `строго больше`, и `count` увеличивать один раз за цикл, наверное, нужно.

Или так, если считать все действия:

```
while b <= n:
    a += b
    count += 1 
    if a > n:
       break
    b += a
    count += 1
```

Если вопрос в оптимизации - нужно присмотреться, какие значения принимают `a` и `b` после `K` попыток. А эти значения выражаются формулами

```
ak = F(k)*a0 + F(k+1)*b0
bk = F(k+1)*a0 + F(k+2)*b0
```

где `F()` - числа Фибоначчи.

Решив целочисленное уравнение (точнее, неравенство) или использовав бинарный поиск, можно найти количество итераций.

Answer (score 0):

для начала вот это

```
data = list(map(int,input().split()))
a = data[0]
b = data[1]
n = data[2]
```

можно схлопнуть вот в это:

```
a, b, n = map(int,input().split())
```

во-вторых вся эта конструкция

```
t = int(input())
i = 0
while i < t:
```

похоже нужна только для

```
for i in range(int(input())):
```

**теперь о самом алгоритме:**

у вас в условии написано

> сделать значение a либо b **строго больше**, чем некоторое данное число

значит требуется не

```
while a < n and b < n:
```

а

```
while a <= n and b <= n:
```

далее смотрите что происходит в вашем коде:

```
    if count % 2 == 1:
        a += b
        count += 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        b += a
        count += 1
```

если `count` нечётный то `count` увеличивается на 1 и становится четным... а дальше опять вы проверяете уже на чётность!!! - в итоге ошибка в логика

надо сделать ВЗАИМОИСКЛЮЧАЮЩИЕ ПРОВЕРКИ

```
    if count % 2 == 1:
        a += b
        count += 1
    else:
        b += a
        count += 1
```

и все, но компактнее записать так:

```
    if count % 2 == 1:
        a += b
    else:
        b += a

    count += 1
```